# Tomcat 7.0.47 session replication issue on cluster

Tags: java, session, tomcat, session-replication

I have 2 web application on my tomcat cluster(consists of 3 tomcat instances)
both run on each tomcat instance.

The tomcat cluster is configured to replicate sessions via BackupManager.

On The first webapp, On new session creation, i get a new session (primary) on the instance , and another instance is getting the Backup session as anticipated.

However, on my second web app, when a session is created, no replication takes place:(

Any ideas why this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set the web.xml of the web application to 
distributable/>